# Is there a way to display ascii as a string?

Tags: html, ascii

While making a CMS I am placing notes within the page, one of those is

`Current Season 2017&#47;2018`

when I run the page it shows as

```
Current Season 2017/2018
```

I want it to display the ascii code when I run the page (html/php) so it reads in the browser as

```
Current Season 2017&#47;2018
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break the & turning it into its entity:

```
&amp;
```

So that

```
2017&amp;#47;2018
```

becomes

```
2017&#47;2018
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the ampersand code to replace the `&`:

```
Current Season 2017&amp;#47;2018
```